# Owl Carousel Not Loading

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, owl-carousel

i want to add the Owl carousel to my webpage but it does not load also there are no error messages in the browser console. Why is the carousel not loading??

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 

 <html>
<head>
<link rel= "stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS_Header.css"/>

<!-- Important Owl stylesheet -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/owl.carousel.css"/>

<!-- Default Theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="owl-carousel/owl.theme.css">
</head>
<body>

<!--  jQuery 1.7+  -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>


<!-- Include js plugin -->
<script src="owl.carousel.js"></script>
<script src="owl.carousel.min.js"></script>

<div id="Items" class="owl-carousel">
  <div><img src="slide1.png"/></div>
  <div><img src="slide1.png"/></div>
  <div><img src="slide1.png"/></div>

<script type="text/css">
  $(document).ready(function() { 
    $("#Items").owlCarousel();

});
</script>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why are you importing `owl.carousel.js` and `owl.carousel.min.js`? the second should be a minified version of the first..

Comment: Even if i remove it, it still does not work

Comment: Take suggestions from @Ninsly answer - if you are still having trouble try to create a fiddle for us to look at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should add the class .item for each item you add on your owl carousel, so the structure is right for the owl-corousel recognize.

```
<div id="Items" class="owl-carousel">
  <div class="item"><img src="slide1.png"/></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="slide1.png"/></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="slide1.png"/></div>

<script type="text/css">
  $(document).ready(function() { 
    $("#Items").owlCarousel();

});
</script>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have javascript in a tag that is labeled `<script type="text/css">`. Try changing it to `<script type="text/javascript">`.

Also, I would suggest putting your scripts in your `<head>`. It's not a good idea to put your script inside the element that it's going to manipulate.

Comment: Thanks it works now but i can't add any functions for the carousel like auto Play it gives me an error unexpected token }

Comment: Well i fixed the error but the slides still don't 'autoPlay'       <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() { 
 $("#Items").owlCarousel({
  autoPlay : 150, 
});
});
</script>

Answer (score 0):

Try with an earlier vesion of jQuery like jquery-1.9.1.min.js